# Receiving JSON files over MQTT

Tags: json, mqtt, esp32, micropython

I am pretty new to micropython and currently I am learning to recieve JSONs over MQTT and I found a piece of code that should automaticaly save a recieved JSON file into a dictionary. I´m pretty sure I understand everything, except for line 3. Can someone help me understand please? (Also, would this actually work?)

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    topic=msg.topic
    m_decode=str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8","ignore"))
    print("data Received type",type(m_decode))
    print("data Received",m_decode)
    print("Converting from Json to Object")
    m_in=json.loads(m_decode)
    print(type(m_in))
    print("broker 2 address = ",m_in["broker2"])
```

Comment: If you want to know if it would actually work why not try it?

Comment: What do you think line 3 does?

Comment: I honestly don´t know what it could do, but my guess is that it saves the recieved file as JSON? Also, I´d like to try it, but the server isn´t ready yet, so I thought I would ask if you can find any obvious mistakes.

Comment: There are plenty of public and freely available MQTT brokers available for you to try with: https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/public_brokers

Comment: I´ll try them, thanks you. I´d still like to know what the line 3 does tho :D

Comment: Data is encoded when sent over a network. Line 3 is decoding it to utf-8 so application can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

If by line 3 you are referring to:

```py
m_decode=str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8","ignore"))
```

Data is received as a series of bytes, or 1s and 0s, which could be used to represent any information you want.

UTF-8 is a standard that says certain strings of 1s and 0s should represent human-readable text characters.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

So the `decode` function turns 1s and 0s in to a UTF-8 text string for your human eyes to read.

https://www.pythoncentral.io/encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-3-x/